# How to compare dates in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

How to compare dates in iReport ? I want to use the "Print When Expression.."

Something like : `$F{date_from_table} <= $F{another_date_from_table} ? true : false`

It should work .

What is the correct syntax? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Date.before() or Date.after() method.
Like below

```
($F{date_from_table}.before($F{another_date_from_table}) || $F{date_from_table}.equals($F{another_date_from_table})) ? true : false
```